# List into a tuple - modifying the list reflects in tuple but emptying the list does not change in tuple

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

Why in the below example does tuple `t` not change when I set `names = []`, yet when I add a new value to the `names` list the change is reflected?

It looked  like `tuple` was initially referencing to the list so any change was reflecting in the tuple object, but emptying it looks like made a new copy.

```
>>> names = ['Mark','Hary']
>>> t = (names,'Lauri')
>>> t
(['Mark', 'Hary'], 'Lauri')
>>> names.append('Donna')
>>> names
['Mark', 'Hary', 'Donna']
>>> t
(['Mark', 'Hary', 'Donna'], 'Lauri')
>>> names = []
>>> names
[]
>>> t
(['Mark', 'Hary', 'Donna'], 'Lauri')
```

Comment: run it through [pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=names%20%3D%20%5B'Mark','Hary'%5D%0At%20%3D%20(names,'Lauri'%29%0Aprint(t%29%0Anames.append('Donna'%29%0Aprint(names%29%0Aprint(t%29%0Anames%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0Aprint(names%29%0Aprint(t%29&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)) it is very useful for visualizing this sort of thing.

Comment: dang it, why can I never get pythontutor links to show correctly... :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`names.append('Donna')` will affect the tuple because the tuple is holding the *same reference to the list object* as `names` does, and you're mutating it in place (`list.append`).

`names = []` is an *assignment* statement that doesn't mutate the reference, it *rebinds* the name `names` to a new object (an empty list in this case). Such a rebinding won't affect the already existing reference inside the tuple.

You could delete *in-place* (i.e modify the list object *referenced* by `names`) and have that change reflected. This can be done in many ways, you could use `names.clear()` or `del names[:]` or even `names[:] = []`:

```
del names[:]
```

after this operation, the reference inside `t` has this change reflected:

```
print(t)
([], 'Lauri')
```

Comment: okay make sense, but when i do `del names` it does not delete the list from `tuple`. what is the different between `del names` and `del names[:]`?

Comment: @VBJ `del names[:]` deletes the *contents* of the list, `del names` removes the name `names` from referring to the list.